# Answering entirely useless questions

Tags: discussion

I just encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688422/form-validation-syntaxerror-unexpected-token). It's a bad question where the answer is fairly obvious and little effort has been put into solving it. More importantly, I doubt it will be useful to anybody else. I tried to close it, but I couldn't find a reason that really addresses this.

What's the correct approach to take here? Should I just answer it, solve that particular user's problem, and move on?

Comment: close as typo and move on. i don't think the fact that it has a dozen vs 1 makes it any different. (wow, that was fast)

Comment: You know, I didn't notice that. Making this a bad question where the answer is fairly obvious and little effort has been put into solving it. There's irony for you.

Comment: Once again, "this question" refers to a post that has been deleted in the meantime...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The appropriate close reason (to which the question has already been closed with) is:

> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."